# Rails: require JS code to pass the Closure Linter or JSHint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, google-closure-compiler, jshint

With Ruby on Rails, is there a configuration I can set that requires the JS code to pass the Closure Linter or JSHint?

You know how when you have a syntax error in your SCSS, an error shows up in dev. I'd like to require something similar with JSHint.

Comment: There are lots of solutions (gems) out there (some for `guard` some for `rake`), but they mostly seem outdated or abandoned.  Did you find a good one you like?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but maybe it will be helpful. You can set up git hooks that will run jshint pre-commit and will either warn or even fails the commit if linter is not satisfied. You can do it manually or use https://github.com/brigade/overcommit and https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/blob/master/lib/overcommit/hook/pre_commit/js_hint.rb

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up an IDE to trigger JShint checker, check out http://jshint.com/install/